# Durandal Unit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, durandal

Does anyone know where to find a good tutorial, example (for durandal beginners) about Unit testing? I read Durandal supports Jasmine, but because my knowledge of that is also very slim, I have no idea how to set this up and use it...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Testing-With-PhantomJS-And-Jasmine.html? Also, I found the following walk-through series rather well-explained https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOxOmO43E6Jt0SruKGxtZs-W3PJN90G_a